# Unable to login to ubuntu laptop after restart with incomplete upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, dell, login-screen, reboot

I have a dell xps laptop. Yesterday I was running Ubuntu 16.04 and was trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from the command line.
. I ran the following commands in the command line

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo ufw allow 1022/tcp
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

My laptop was restarted in the middle of the upgrade process and now I cannot login to my laptop. When I turn it on in sequence there was 
1.the black dell screen,
2. the purple Ubuntu screen with loading dots, 
3. black screen with white text “booting in insecure mode”
4. black screen with white text of "scanning for btrf file systems" there were some files found and many blocks,with a white blinking underscore cursor.
I left this screen for many hours and it never moved to the login screen. I then tried to do BIOS setup and my laptop is now stuck on a white dell screen which say 
Warning Message Operating System Loader failed signature verification.WARNING: The file may have been tampered with! All bootable devices failed Secure Boot verification[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjBqY.jpg) with picture attached.
I have read 10 other askubuntu that are selected and contacted dellsupport but they do not offer support with ubuntu.
I have tried pressing both Ctrl+Alt+F1 and Ctrl+Alt+F3 when I first turn on my laptop but it still goes to the white screen.

I have escaped white screen by changing the boot setting to 
UEFI Boot Mode,Secure Boot Off.
But I am now back at the black screen with

Scanning for Btrfs filesystems 
/dev/nveme0n1p3: clean 1301938/28827658 files,68548085/115291408 blocks
white blinking underscore
My ideal scenario is to be able to login to my ubuntu system. Thanks for any help or advice

Comment: My mistake, the upgrade should probably be to 18.04.  I had run the following commands in the command line 
>>sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
>>sudo ufw allow 1022/tcp
>>sudo do-release-upgrade